# Converting a "name" to a real, then convert it back to a string

Tags: game-maker, gml, game-maker-studio-2, game-maker-language

I've ran into some issues with my current gamemaker project. I've setup a simple "merge" functionality in my game, and I'm trying to increase it's QoL

So what's happening when I'm merging, is this;

```
var sabatons = instance_place(x, y, object_index);
if (instance_exists(sabatons)) {
    instance_create_layer(sabatons.lastknownPosX, sabatons.lastknownPosY, "Instances", "");

    if (level >= 3) {
        scr_spawn_experience(); 
    }

    audio_play_sound(snd_sabatons_merge,10,false);

    instance_destroy();
    instance_destroy(sabatons);
}
```

So what the code above does, is to check if `object_index` matches with what I'm trying to merge it with, and if it does, it runs `instance_create_layer` - which is where my question comes in.

My objects are easily named with a digit at the end, to keep track of their "level"
so basically, `obj_sabatons_1` means it's the first item in a chain, `obj_sabatons_2` is the second etc. Now what I need help with is to convert whatever the object is that I'm trying to merge with, to a string (object_index) but increase it with 1, so I then can put that result in my `instance_create_layer` so the game will create the next level of item, if I successfully merge my first two items :)

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason that the level should be part of the name? If not, then you could convert the level into a variable of the object `obj_sabatons`, so you can keep all the code related to `obj_sabatons` in one place (And then remove all those copied objects with digits at the end)

Making multiple copies of the same object can be disadvantageous in numerous ways, For example, if you want to expand the limit, then you'd have to create a new object for each level, making a code change also means changing that code in every other object level (unless you're making use of parents/child objects), it would also make the progress of merging objects into new objects easier

Comment: I am using a parent object for all my "sabaton" objects :)
but yes, "level" needs to be a part of the game, to keep track of what current level the item is in :)